# How to update value of a key of all objects from array of dictionary in swift3 without enumeration?

Tags: ios, swift3

How to update the value of a key of all objects from an array of a dictionary in swift3 without enumeration?

E.g

```
let tags = [Dict("key1":true, "key2":1),Dict("key1":true,
"key2":2),Dict("key1":false, "key2":3),Dict("key1":true, "key2":1),
Dict("key1": false, "key2":1)]
```

Now I want to change the value if `"key1":false` for all Dict objects.

i.e I need output like this

```
tag : [Dict("key1": false, "key2":1),Dict("key1": false,
"key2":2),Dict("key1":false, "key2":3),Dict("key1": false, "key2":1),
Dict("key1": false, "key2":1)]
```

Can I achieve this without enumeration or iterations? and How?

Comment: Your code is not valid.

Comment: what is `Dict`?

Comment: Why would you not use an iterator? Is not the whole point of a Sequence that its iterable?

Comment: You will have to iterate over the array, either explicitly or implicitly.  e.g. the answer below using `map` still iterates over the array, it is just "hidden".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function:

```
let tags = [
    ["key1": true,  "key2": 1],
    ["key1": true,  "key2": 2],
    ["key1": false, "key2": 3],
    ["key1": true,  "key2": 1],
    ["key1": false, "key2": 1]]

let newTags = tags.map { (dict) -> [String : Any] in
    // dict is immutable, so you need a mutable shadow copy:
    var dict = dict

    dict["key1"] = false
    return dict
}
```

This function is implicitly still iterating as mentioned by Paulw11. In the general case you *have* to iterate over the entries if you need to update them all.

Depending on your data you may be able to model the value to be updated with reference types. This could be beneficial for huge datasets where large known groups of data share the same state.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this, but it still iterates

Comment: True. But in the end you need to touch all dictionaries if you want to update an entry in each of them, right? Iterating is the way to do this in the general case. What is the problem with iterating in your case?

Comment: It is impossible to do this *without* iterating.  I was merely pointing out that this solution has an implicit iteration

Comment: Well yes, but I think that is labouring the point. In theory any loop can be unwound to a series of discrete accesses. Indeed, if you have a massively parallel processor, such as a DSP or super computer then loop unwinding is a common technique and the compiler can perform this optimisation for you.

Comment: @Paulw11: Sorry, I deleted my comment before seeing your answer. I thought it would be better to add to my answer instead.